# React Router Dom Protected Routes Keep redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am making protected routes. am using redux and pure react app and React Router Dom. The problem am face when I go to `/profile/edit` and hit refresh then it redirects me to `/login` > `/profile`. I created a protected route. I want to make something like when I am on `isAuthenticated` page it will stay on that page. I don't want it to redirect me to `/profile`. I put my `protectedRoute` in `element` and having the issue. Now I am using it inside of `loader`. but now my `protected route` is not working. Can someone please tell me how I can do this? or give me any idea? Thank you

```
// App.js

<Routes>
  <Route
    element={
      <ProtectedRoute
        isAuthenticatedRoute={false}
        sendTo={"/profile"}
      />
    }
  >
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  </Route>

  {/* Profile Pages */}
  <Route
    element={
      <ProtectedRoute
        isAuthenticatedRoute={true}
        sendTo={"/login"}
      />
    }
  >
    <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
    <Route path="/profile/category" element={<EditCategory />} />
    <Route path="/profile/edit" element={<EditProfile />} />
  </Route>

  {/* Page Not Found */}
  <Route path="/*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
</Routes>

// App.js with loader

<Routes>
  <Route
    loader={
      <ProtectedRoute
        isAuthenticatedRoute={false}
        sendTo={"/profile"}
      />
    }
  >
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>

// ProtectedRoutes.js

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import AppLoader from "../AllLoader/AppLoader/AppLoader";
import { useLoadUserQuery } from "../../redux/feature/apiSlice/apiSlice";

const ProtectedRoute = ({
  isAuthenticatedRoute,
  children,
  adminRoute,
  isAdmin,
  sendTo,
}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isLoading } = useLoadUserQuery(undefined, undefined);

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <AppLoader />;
  }

  const isAuthenticated = user;

  if (isAuthenticatedRoute && !isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />;
  }
  if (!isAuthenticatedRoute && isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/profile" replace={true} />;
  }

  return children ? children : <Outlet />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

```
My redux store
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import newsSliceReducer from "./feature/newsSlice/newsSlice";
import authSliceReducer from "./feature/userSlice/authSlice";
import profileSliceReducer from "./feature/profileSlice/profileSlice";
import languageSliceReducer from "./feature/languageSlice/languageSlice";
import otherSliceReducer from "./feature/otherSlice/otherSlice";
import { apiSlice } from "./feature/apiSlice/apiSlice";
import { getUserProfile, refreshToken } from "./feature/userSlice/authApi";

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        // For Getting all news
        allNews: newsSliceReducer,

        // For Authorization
        auth: authSliceReducer,

        // For user Profile
        profile: profileSliceReducer,

        // For others Data
        other: otherSliceReducer,

        // For Langauge which will be used later
        languages: languageSliceReducer,
    },

    // devTools: false,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});

// Here will call the Get profile and refresh topke

const initializeApp = async () => {
    await store.dispatch(
        apiSlice.endpoints.refreshToken.initiate({}, { forceRefetch: true })
    );
    await store.dispatch(
        apiSlice.endpoints.loadUser.initiate({}, { forceRefetch: true })
    );

    // await store.dispatch(refreshToken());
    // await store.dispatch(getUserProfile());
};

initializeApp();

export default store;


//apiSlice

import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { SERVER } from "../../../utils/backend";
import { userValue } from "../userSlice/authSlice";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: "api",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: SERVER }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        refreshToken: builder.query({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: "/user/refresh-token",
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include",
            }),
        }),

        // Load users
        loadUser: builder.query({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: "/user/me",
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include",
            }),

            async onQueryStarted(arg, { queryFulfilled, dispatch }) {
                try {
                    const result = await queryFulfilled;
                    dispatch(
                        userValue({
                            token: result.data.accessToken,
                            user: result.data.user,
                        })
                    );
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            },
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useRefreshTokenQuery, useLoadUserQuery } = apiSlice;


My ApiSlice
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
    activateUser,
    getUserProfile,
    refreshToken,
    userLogin,
    userLogout,
    userRegister,
} from "./authApi";

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        authLoading: false,
        getUserProfileLoading: false,
        refreshTokenLoading: false,
        user: null,
        userActivationToken: "",
        authError: null,
        authMessage: null,
        getUserProfileMessage: null,
        getUserProfileError: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        clearAuthMessage: (state) => {
            state.authMessage = null;
        },
        clearAuthError: (state) => {
            state.authError = null;
        },
        clearUserProfileError: (state) => {
            state.getUserProfileError = null;
        },

        userValue: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload.user;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        // Register

        builder.addCase(userRegister.pending, (state) => {
            state.authLoading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(userRegister.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.authMessage = action.payload.message;
            state.userActivationToken = action.payload.activationToken;
        });

        builder.addCase(userRegister.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.authError = action.payload.message;
        });

        // Login

        builder.addCase(userLogin.pending, (state) => {
            state.authLoading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(userLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.authMessage = action.payload.message;
        });

        builder.addCase(userLogin.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.authError = action.payload.message;
        });

        // Logout =================================================================

        builder.addCase(userLogout.pending, (state) => {
            state.authLoading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(userLogout.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.user = null;
            state.authMessage = action.payload.message;
        });

        builder.addCase(userLogout.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.authError = action.payload.message;
        });

        // =========================    Active User        ========================================

        builder.addCase(activateUser.pending, (state) => {
            state.authLoading = true;
        });

        builder.addCase(activateUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.authMessage = action.payload.message;
        });

        builder.addCase(activateUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.authLoading = false;
            state.authError = action.payload.message;
        });

        // =========================    Refresh token     ========================================

        builder.addCase(refreshToken.pending, (state) => {
            state.refreshTokenLoading = true;
        });

        builder.addCase(refreshToken.fulfilled, (state) => {
            state.refreshTokenLoading = false;
        });

        builder.addCase(refreshToken.rejected, (state) => {
            state.refreshTokenLoading = false;
        });

        //========================================  Get User Profile     ========================================

        builder.addCase(getUserProfile.pending, (state) => {
            state.getUserProfileLoading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(getUserProfile.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.getUserProfileLoading = false;
            state.user = action.payload.user;
        });

        builder.addCase(getUserProfile.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.getUserProfileLoading = false;
            state.getUserProfileError = action.payload.message;
        });
    },
});

export const {
    clearAuthMessage,
    clearAuthError,
    clearUserProfileError,
    userValue,
} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;


My index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Am expecting when am on any **authenticated** page, it will stay there. It won't redirect me at first `/login` > `/profile` page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `useLoadUserQuery` query's `isLoading` status isn't set true until *after* the initial render cycle has completed and the query could be initiated in the component. I suspect that on the initial render cycle that `isLoading` is false and that `ProtectedRoute` uses the initial state value `null` of the selected `state.auth.user` value that results in the rendering of one of the `Navigate` components to redirect the user.

My suggestion would be to start `state.auth.user` from an indeterminant value, e.g. `undefined` and also explicitly check for this value when loading.

Example:

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    authLoading: false,
    getUserProfileLoading: false,
    refreshTokenLoading: false,
    user: undefined, // <-- initially undefined
    userActivationToken: "",
    authError: null,
    authMessage: null,
    getUserProfileMessage: null,
    getUserProfileError: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    ...
  },
});
```

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
  isAuthenticatedRoute,
  children,
  adminRoute,
  isAdmin,
  sendTo,
}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isLoading } = useLoadUserQuery(undefined, undefined);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);

  if (isLoading || user === undefined) { // <-- loading, or undefined user
    return <AppLoader />;
  }

  const isAuthenticated = !!user;

  if (isAuthenticatedRoute && !isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }
  if (!isAuthenticatedRoute && isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/profile" replace />;
  }

  return children ?? <Outlet />;
};
```

A more conventional route protection implementation would separate the logic of protecting certain routes from unauthenticated users from the logic of protecting certain routes from authenticated users. Modify `ProtectedRoute` to *only* redirect unauthenticated users and create another component to do the inverse for the login-type routes.

Example:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isLoading } = useLoadUserQuery(undefined, undefined);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);

  if (isLoading || user === undefined) {
    return <AppLoader />;
  }

  const isAuthenticated = !!user;
  
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }

  return children ?? <Outlet />;
};
```

```
const AnonymousRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isLoading } = useLoadUserQuery(undefined, undefined);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);

  if (isLoading || user === undefined) {
    return <AppLoader />;
  }

  const isAuthenticated = !!user;

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/profile" replace />;
  }

  return children ?? <Outlet />;
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AnonymousRoute />}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  </Route>

  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}>
    <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
    <Route path="/profile/category" element={<EditCategory />} />
    <Route path="/profile/edit" element={<EditProfile />} />
  </Route>

  <Route path="/*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
</Routes>
```